# MSBuild: How to build web deploy package for Web Deployment Projects (VS2010)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, webdeploy

I migrated a Web Site project (with Web Deployment project) from VS2008 to VS2010. Now I can make "Build Deployment Package" for Web Deployment Project in VS2010 and it works great! But I can't find a way how to do the same via MSBuild.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I answer on my one question. So after a lot of googling and 2 days of investigation it finally works.

Brief how to:

1. I created Configuration = QA (based on Debug configuration) for Solution via Configuration Manager.
2. Important: **I removed 'Platform' parameter for QA Configuration. I couldn't build package until I did it.** (My dev computer is Win7-x64, and I'm not not sure would be this step necessary for x86. But my build server Win2008-x86 forks fine with this modification.)  This is QA Configuration section from my .wdproj

   ```
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'QA' ">
   <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
   <OutputPath>QA\</OutputPath>
   <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
   <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
   <SingleAssemblyName>
   </SingleAssemblyName>
   <UseWebConfigReplacement>false</UseWebConfigReplacement>
   <DeleteAppDataFolder>true</DeleteAppDataFolder>
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <ExcludeApp_Data>true</ExcludeApp_Data>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
3. I build and package .wbproj file with the following command:

   ```
   msbuild WebSite.Deploy.wdproj /t:Build;Package /p:Configuration=QA
   ```

**For information**: If you need you can use standard Web Publishing parameters (e.g. ExcludeApp_Data, DeployIisAppPath etc.) in the QA configuration section.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MSBuild YourProject.csproj /T:Package
```

That should generate a deployment package. This page, [How to: Use MSBuild to Create a Web Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547591.aspx) **might** give a bit more information, but not much.

Comment: I do not have .csproj. The site is a Web Site project and doesn't have project file at all (That's why I use a Web Deployment project). The web deployment project has extension .wdproj and do not understand Target=Package

Comment: ahh, i missed that even though its right there in your question.  I don't have any experience with web site projects and based on the comments from ScottGu's blog, it doesn't look like its supported?  Thats kind of old, so I don't know how relative it is.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx

Comment: I found out that Web Deploy has Target=Package, but it didn't work for me until I made change #2 (see my answer).